# Why not backslash every empty space to prevent mysql injections

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-injection

I've been wondering this for maybe a few months now but I still don't know an answer, other then possible speed performance. So long story short, instead of having all this PDO codes everywhere, why not just put a backslash between every character?

```
$String = $_POST["attack"];   // SOME THING' OR 1 = 1 --
$String = fFilter( $String ); // \S\O\M\E\ \T\H\I\N\G\'\ \O\R\ \1\ \=\ \1\ \-\-
```

Now I haven't been into this SQL stuff in awhile, so I can't give a perfect example, but basically the sql string should look like this `SELECT * FROM account WHERE id = '\S\O\M\E\ \T\H\I\N\G\'\ \O\R\ \1\ \=\ \1\ \-\-'` and something like that just always seemed pretty safe, but I haven't heard of anyone using it, or even why not to use it. I always see things like filtering html and etc isn't good, but I don't see why not just filter every single character. Since any attack would look like `\a\t\t\a\c\k`.

Comment: Why not prepare every statement to prevent mysql injections?

Comment: Some sequences like `\n` represent something _different_ than the originally intended `n`.  The problem of SQL injection has been pretty handily solved through parameterized queries.

Comment: @DaveChen Because no one says anything is 100% safe, even if it is PDO.

Comment: Nothing is 100% safe, but preparing will protect you from injections. Now XSS or overflows are still possible.

Comment: no, you are right, a lot of lazy people do this with addslashes function. the best way is to use prepared sql statements. look it up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because placing a backslash before certain characters changes their meaning entirely. For instance, `\t` is a tab character, not `t`, so `\a\t\t\a\c\k` would be transformed to:

```
a       ack
```

A full list of such sequences is given at:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-literals.html

As several other people have mentioned, use parameterized queries, not input escaping.

Comment: I know that but I wasn't thinking about sql. I was thinking about PHP and how "\n" is a line break but '\n' is really a backslash then n.

Comment: @Hybrilynx The use of the two quotes are very different. the `'bla'` is literal. Which means anything passed into the single quote will be treated as input. Whereas the double quotes allow for PHP to interpret special characters as, well. What they actually represent

Comment: @Hybrilynx: While there are some similiarities, PHP and MySQL treat single quotes differently. (The set of backslash escapes isn't even the same between the two; it's just very similar.)